# Is there any constraint to use fixed position in CSS?

Tags: css, css-position

I think fixed position can be useful in web designing, but is there any constraint  in browsers or in responsive designing for fixed div?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed - and, in particular, [this article](http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose in addition to checking support for this, the other constraint would be to ensure that it doesn't obscure content in the various media - the same checking you would perform when implementing responsive design.